# Alternate full speed usb library for ATTINY85?

Tags: usb, attiny, attiny85

I'm currently working on a project using the ATTINY85 for USB communication. After some research, it turns out that the V-USB library only supports usb 1.1, which only supports a 125hz polling rate. I would like to be able to have a polling rate of 1000hz, or close to it, which requires usb 2.0 or faster. I was hoping that someone could help point me to a library which supports usb 2.0, or suggest an alternative. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: you need a dedicated USB controller for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an ATtiny85 has no built-in USB hardware module, you use a software solution like V-USB. Unfortunately bit-banging software cannot be as fast as hardware, so you are out of luck here. (Reading the documentation of V-USB is enlightened and explains the difficulties and limits of such a solution.)

You cannot have USB 2.0 with an ATtiny85 alone.

Possible solutions:

- an external USB module
- another microcontroller